# How to make Control bone affect only wanted Bones

Tags: rigging

Rotating CTRL_Tweak_Chest.002 ,selected on picture, on Y axis affect both front legs and neck all the way to the head. How to make it rotate only front legs, without affecting neck, head rotation.

Rig here: [image]

[image]

Comment: It depends on how is the rig built, you can upload it https://blend-exchange.com/ (it's ok to upload the rig only). You can try to select the TGT_Neck.001 bone, and uncheck its "Inherit rotation" option in the bones properties > relations panel (pose and edit mode), but it's not sure it will work (it depends by the architecture of the rig).

Comment: Tried but doesn't work. Added the .blend file, so if you can see - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the "Inherit rot" parameter doesn't work because TGT_Neck.001 bone is part of an IK Chain, so its rot is overwritten by the IK solver.

To have the rig behave as you want you can add a machinary bone, extruded from CTRL_TWEAK_Chest.002, with the same axis orientations, uncheck its "Inherit rot" and its "Deform" options.

Then in edit mode you have to set 3 bones child (keep offset) of this newly created bone (I called it MCH_Head_Base): TGT_Neck.001, DEF_Neck.001 and IK_Head_Target.

I added to the new bone a copy rot constraint, targeting CTRL_TWEAK_Chest.002, so that you can use its influence slider to choose between the old head rotation mode (influence = 1.0) and the new independent one (influence = 0.0).

Some more work it's needed if you want the whole character to rigidly rotate when you rotate the root bone (as it should), but how to it depends by how you want to organize the rig.

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! Just the control I wanted to have. Thanks for sharing. I see you are very experienced in rigging. May I ask you where can I put my rig to get some tips, critiques, advices since Stack Overflow is not for opinion based Questions? There is not a lot of tutorials for Rigging, there are some good humanoid rigs, but for quadruped or anything similiar not so advanced.

Comment: I don't know much about forums, but I can sugget you this old free rigging course https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3J-XN38EnhQ&list=PLE211C8C41F1AFBAB&index=1. Also Level pixel level has advanced tips, and CG Dive for expanding the use of Rigify Addon for animals and special creatures https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCRSx63y-VPidCrycgDS-o_Q.

Comment: Thanks for assistance, looking forward to watch those.